# 7+ seconds load time for https request most of the time; sometimes only 300ms

Tags: ssl, https

I have a site hosted on Siteground that is the only one of around 10 I have on my account there that has very long load times between transferring from http to https. Here are two GTMetrix reports that show you what the load times are like when, for some reason, sometimes there is hardly any load time between the http to https transfer (very rare and brief). The second report shows you what is almost always the case...there is 6-7 seconds of load time when going from http to https.

Fast http to https: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/upliftguide.com/MQj905Ls
Slow http to https: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/upliftguide.com/mnGyRkUU

I've spoken with my webhost (Siteground) already and even after using the Better Search Replace plugin to replace all http links with https, I'm having this issue. They assured me there's no issues on the server-side, but I don't know what the exceptionally long https request load time could be stemming from.

Any ideas what could be the issue here? I am using Let's Encrypt for the SSL, which comes as an option to turn on in the  cpanel. I don't have https enforce activated on this or any of my other sites; just have Let's Encrypt active. I'm on a shared hosting server with no dedicated IP address.

Here's another one of my sites on the same server also using Let's Encrypt, and loading https very fast: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/hiptreasure.com/w0YEnWfM

I'm using Siteground's in-house caching plugin on all my websites (which works really well), including the one having issues.

Comment: Why not use your browser to shoe the breakdown of where the delay comes in. Eg look at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/

Comment: I know where the delay is...it's at the https request. Here's a screenshot of in the devtools: https://prnt.sc/rs2dxp

Comment: I would like to add that I spoke with Let's Encrypt and it doesn't seem to be the SSL causing the slow load time, since the SSL itself loads in 117.5ms. They said 7 seconds to create the Html-Content may be because of a slow database, or maybe missing or wrong indices. The thing is, I literally just created the website a few days ago, so what could be stalling the loading of the content so much?

Screenshot of the breakdown: https://prnt.sc/rs3fzm

Comment: I worked this out and it turns out, Siteground's SG Optimizer plugin has an option to configure the site to work correctly via HTTPS and forces a secure connection to your site, so once that was disabled, there's no more long load times of https. I really thought it was something more complex than that, but there it is!